# Hiding context menu based on data trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a couple of grids in a user control. I want to hide the context menu in a grid based on a property in the DataContext. I have this code:

```
   <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLockedNorthGrid}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I know the IsLockedNorthGrid property works since I'm using it somewhere else in xaml. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for the place it is working and possibly the IsLockedNorthGrid object?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Style.Triggers to change the Visibility, be sure you are not setting Visibility to Context Menu inline.  Since, inline property has higher priority over the style.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Visibility is set to a specific value (setting it in a specific element and triggering it won´t work). Also try

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLockedNorthGrid}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The context menu appears regardless. If I do just <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"> without the trigger the menu does not appear so it appears it has something to do with the trigger and property?

Comment: Yep, probably. Two possibilities: The binding doesn´t work somehow (but I guess this would cause an error) or it´s always set to true. Maybe try invert the trigger and see what happens (set Value="True")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem like so:

```
<XamDataGrid ContextMenuOpeninig="OnContextMenuOpening">
<XamDataGrid.Resources>   
<ContextMenu x:Key="GridContextMenu">...</ContextMenu> </XamDataGrid.Resources> 
<XamDataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
{
    var logViewModel = (LogViewModelBase)DataContext;
    var grid = sender as XamDataGrid;
    var menu = grid.Resources["GridContextMenu"] as ContextMenu;

    menu.Visibility = !logViewModel.IsLockedNorthGrid ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Not that pretty but it works.